# Z3: Parse Term from String

Tags: c, parsing, z3

Is there a Z3 C API call that parses a general (non-Boolean) term? E.g. something like this: `(+ a b)`? As far as I see it, the `Z3_parse_smtlib2_string` function parses only formulas in assertions, which are exclusively of Boolean type.

Comment: Doesn't something like `define-fun sum () Int (+ x y)` satisfy you, and why not? What have you tried so far, and how did it fail?

Comment: Michael, I've tried to parse something like that previously with `Z3_parse_smtlib2_string`, but it only returns the term `true`.

Comment: z3 is a solver for SAT Modulo Theories, therefore its result is True or False (SAT or UNSAT), what result do you expect from that example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser (Z3_parse_smtlib2_string) parses SMT-LIB2 benchmarks. Benchmarks in this format define a logical formula. This formula is "true" if the input does not contain any assertions. This is why the parser returns "true" in your case. Z3 doesn't expose parsing facilities for terms. You can work around this by creating a special predicate "MyHolds" that takes a term of the suitable type.
You then create a benchmark that has the assertion "(assert (MyHolds ))" as the only assertion. You can then remove the MyHolds from the result of the parser to get back your term.